# How to write software to compile with external libraries?

Tags: make, c, dependencies, opensource-projects

I want to code open source software with dependencies. I have skills in C/C++ and a minimum makefile knowledge. But im curious about coding this like `./configure && make` stuff and how to include dependencies to other libraries properly.

Where can I find a easy to understand tutorial and is it a hard thing to learn it?

Comment: There are a lot of options for building and configuring, not just `make/autoconf`. Personally, I use `scons`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe either configure or make is hard to learn.  However, they are complex, so they can be tricky to learn - especially through experimentation.  For example, make requires commands to build a target are indented strictly with a TAB character, which is hard to distinguish from spaces in many cases.

Here's a page that goes over both of those (and more): http://autotoolset.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#Compiling-with-Makefiles.

And a page on the GNU standards for configuration: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html.

Note that `autoconf` is the tool for creating configure scripts; of course, you can home-grow your own configure script, but `autoconf` will get you the standard type of script and should save a lot of programming effort.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it is done with `autoconf`.  I don't have any tutorial in particular to recommend (beyond the official documentation), but you will need one and that is what you want to look for.  "Autoconf" colloquially refers to a suite of tools including 'automake'.

I have not done it for a while, but I'll try to sketch out the process from my notes:

- For each source directory (don't put your sources in the top level, put them in subdirectories), you need to create a `Makefile.am`; this follows the rules for a normal makefile, but does not include compilation targets, and instead defines some targets and variables following a naming scheme specific to the autoconf process.  This will be processed by `automake`.
- In the top level, you need to create a `configure.ac` file.  The `autoscan` tool can do this for you and then you can tweak it.
- You then need to run, in order from the top level directory: `aclocal`, `automake -ac`, `autoheader` (and possibly `automake -ac` again), then `autoconf`.  These all have man pages that explain their purpose.

Presto! Your package is ready.

> is it a hard thing to learn it?

It's definitely *tedious* and I would not call it super easy, no.  If your project is small and you are only targeting particular platforms, you could just come up with a dependency checking script of your own that can be run from the makefile.

Comment: Some other tools that can be helpful in hiding some the cruft: [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) + [premake4](http://industriousone.com/premake).